# incorrect length using zip with for loop in python

Tags: python

I having trouble with for loop in the code below, it seems that because of different length I receive output that not numered as it should be

```
for (title, year) in (zip(title_elements, release_year)):
    title_output = title.get_text(strip=True)
    year_output = year.get_text(strip=True)

    if year_output.isdigit() and len(year_output) == 4:
        print(title_output, year_output)
```

full code: https://pastebin.com/EEM85q15

output: https://pastebin.com/FLm4Dfv0

Comment: Are you confused about the behavior of `zip` when given two differently-sized sequences? Because the code you posted is fine. It's your data extraction that is broken but that's not the code you posted and asked about

Comment: Change your title to reflect the real issue

Comment: Were any of these solutions helpful in resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Adding one single line of code makes everything work as expected. Your initial variable 'release_year' captured the (release_year, movie_rating, and run_time) for each movie. Therefore you need to take every third item from that list to get just the run times.

```
    metadata_items = soup.find_all(class_="sc-b85248f1-6 bnDqKN cli-title-metadata-item")
    release_year = metadata_items[::3]
```